# Grouping/Bucketing latitude and longitude

Tags: python, algorithm, latitude-longitude, geo, geography

This is more of a logical problem than the technical one. So request you guys to please not to flag it.

I want to write a method in python, that takes two parameters -> latitude and longitude. This method should return group/bucket. The grouping should be done based on 0.05 degree.

```
def get_bucket(lat,lng):
  #body
```

Eg:

get_bucket(1.05,1.05) -> b1
get_bucket(1.05,1.03) -> b1

So its like assuming that the earth is divided in 0.05 degree grid square and any lat/long falling in this square share the same bucket.

Comment: Initial thought would be to just divide and floor, but `0.15 / 0.05` is not quite 3 for example. Multiply by 100 and floor divide by 5 perhaps?

Comment: Since the earth is not flat, your buckets will get progressively more triangular as you approach the poles. That means that, roughly speaking, your biggest buckets will be where there are more people, which may be really bad if your problem domain is at all influenced by human population. (Of course, that doesn't matter if you're only interested in a small patch of the globe, particularly if the patch is near the equator.)

Comment: So what's your question? Have you tried anything at all? If you wanted to put all the integers between 0 and 1000 into buckets based on the result of dividing them by 2, how many buckets would you need? If you can solve that problem then you can solve this one.

Answer (score 7):

There are typically 180 degrees of latitude (-90 to 90) and 360 degrees of longitude (-180 to 180).

So there are 18,000 hundredth-degree increments of latitude (i.e. -90.00, -89.99, ... 89.99, 90.00), and 36,000 hundredth-degree increments of longitude.

Let's say you put this in a two-dimensional array. If you want .05 degree increments, you'll need 3,600 (18,000/5) rows for latitude, and 7,200 columns (36,000/5) rows for latitude.

So you want to convert a longitude/latitude into two array indices. Here's one way:

1. Take your latitude number, which will be in the range -90 to 90, and add 90 to it. That gives you a number from 0 to 180.
2. Multiply by 100, and round up. That gives you a number from 0 to 18,000.
3. Divide by 5.

That's your row index.

Do the same with longitude, but add 180 to get a number between 0 and 360. That provides your column number.

Example:

The location of Austin, TX is lat: 30.267, lng: -97.743

```
30.267 + 90 = 120.267
120.267 * 100 = 12027 (rounded up)
12027 / 5 = 2405

-97.743 + 180 = 82.257
82.257 * 100 = 8226 (rounded up)
8226 / 5 = 1645
```

So Austin, TX would go into bucket (2450,1645)

Of course, transforming the indexes back to latitude and longitude is just a reverse of the original transformation. For latitude, multiply by 5, divide by 100, and subtract 90.

Edit: Corrected math error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one implementation:

```
def get_bucket(lat,lng):
    int(lng/0.05)*(whatever the highest possible lat is)/0.05 + int(lat/0.05)
```

Comment: what is this "whatever the highest possible lat is"

Comment: @Juvenik 90 degrees? The planet is spherical.

Comment: @Andrey I don't know... A lot of people these days think it's flat.  ;)

Comment: @devinbost I hope they are not developing geospatial applications.